# How to scroll up a div when hovering over another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an absolute div that is behind my footer. When I hover over another element (#snapchat) I want that absolute div to scroll up from behind the footer and stop above it where it can be seen. How would I do this?

```css
.snapcode-footer { 
  position: absolute;
  padding-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.sub-sub-footer {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #F7F7F7;
  padding-top: 35px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.sub-footer {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #edeeef;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="snapcode-footer">
<img src="https://wumbo.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/snapcode.png" width="250px" height="auto" alt="Scan to add us on Snapchat!">
</div>

<div class="sub-sub-footer">
 <ul class="social-footer">
    <li id="twitter"><a href="https://www.twitter.com/wumbo" target="blank"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/Twitter-color.png" alt="Follow us on Twitter @wumbo"/></a></li>
    <li id="snapchat"><a href="#"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/Snapchat-color.png" alt="Follow us on Snapchat @wumbo"/></a></li>
    <li id="insta"><a href="https://www.instagram.com/wumbo" target="blank"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/Instagram-color.png" alt="Follow us on Instagram @wumbo"/></a></li>
    <li id="facebook"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/wumbo" target="blank"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/Facebook-color.png" alt="Follow us on Facebook @wumbo"/></a></li>
 </ul>
</div>

    <div class="sub-footer">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-md-5-footer">
        <div class="footer-img">    
            <img src="https://www.wumbo.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/HullSpar_Slogan.png" alt="Made For The Modern Seafarer™"/>
        <div/>  
                </div>

            </div>
```

Comment: Do you want it to rise every time the mouse hovers over, or to rise all at once when the mouse hovers over?

Comment: I want .snapcode-footer to rise every time someone hovers over #snapchat and then fall back behind the footer when they no longer hover over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm re-positioned your `div.snapcode` footer and applied a css property to

**#snapchat:hover ~ .snapcode-footer** . hopes this will help you :)

```css
.snapcode-footer { 
  position: absolute;
  padding-top: 90px;
  text-align: center;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.sub-sub-footer {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #F7F7F7;
  padding-top: 35px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.sub-footer {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #edeeef;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

#snapchat:hover ~ .snapcode-footer{
  z-index:999;
  color:green;
  position:relative;
  margin-bottom:100px;
  margin-left:50px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="sub-sub-footer">
 <ul class="social-footer">
    <li id="twitter"><a href="https://www.twitter.com/hullandspar" target="blank"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/Twitter-color.png" alt="Follow us on Twitter @hullandspar"/></a></li>
    <li id="snapchat"><a href="#"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/Snapchat-color.png" alt="Follow us on Snapchat @hullandspar"/></a></li>
   <div class="snapcode-footer">
<img src="https://hullandspar.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/snapcode.png" width="250px" height="auto" alt="Scan to add us on Snapchat!">
</div>
    <li id="insta"><a href="https://www.instagram.com/hullandspar" target="blank"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/Instagram-color.png" alt="Follow us on Instagram @hullandspar"/></a></li>
    <li id="facebook"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/hullandspar" target="blank"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/Facebook-color.png" alt="Follow us on Facebook @hullandspar"/></a></li>
 </ul>
</div>

    <div class="sub-footer">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-md-5-footer">
        <div class="footer-img">    
            <img src="https://www.hullandspar.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/HullSpar_Slogan.png" alt="Made For The Modern Seafarer™"/>
        </div>  
                </div>

            </div>
```

Comment: After a few tweaks this worked great. I will have to learn more about using "~" in css. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest giving snapcode-footer an id to make it easier to control.

```
<div class="snapcode-footer" id="snapcode">
```

`<script>
var hover = 0;
</script>`

Then you make a script on #snapchat

`<li id="snapchat"`**onmouseenter="hover = 1" onmouseout="hover = 0"**`><a href="#"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/Snapchat-color.png" alt="Follow us on Snapchat @hullandspar"/></a></li>`

Lastly, you make a script for if the mouse is hovering over the #snapchat element to increase height or to stay in one place

```
<script>
setInterval("if(hover == 1){snapcode.top--}");
setInterval("if(hover == 0){snapcode.top = 0}");
</script>
```